# $.when.apply in Angular AJAX promise implementation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, promise

Is there a way to do the equivalent of

```
 $.when.apply( [ $.ajax(), $.ajax() ]).done(function(){
      // all the ajax's are done now...
 })
```

in AngularJS's `$http.get()` promise system?

Comment: The question is, why would you when you can set the the `$scope` of your function to the result of the ajax call ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `$q.all([async1, async2]).then(...)`

```
$q.all([promise, …]) → newPromise
```

The *newPromise* will resolve once all the given promises have been resolved

See Docs <kbd>[HERE](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q#methods_all)</kbd>